# The tone the last syllable of a word

Tags: tone, vietnamese

[bảo tàng](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/), the last tone is huyền. However, you can hear it pronounced as a rising tone pattern in [Google Translate](https://translate.google.ca/?sl=auto&tl=zh-TW&text=B%E1%BA%A3o%20t%C3%A0ng&op=translate).

Please tell me what's the cause of the change?

Comment: I'd recommend doing some reading up on tone sandhi: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_sandhi

Comment: @Tristan This has no relevanxe for Vietnamese.

Comment: I do not hear a rising tone on tàng.

Comment: @fdb true, that was me jumping to conclusions before reading properly

Comment: The tone is the same as if you get Google Translate to pronounce _huyền_. It does sound like a (slightly) rising tone – definitely not 21 or 31 as Wikipedia describes the huyền tone. Possibly it’s simply an error in Google Translate’s voice synthesis for Vietnamese.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I thougjt, naively, that it was a real person.

Comment: @fdb No, it’s computer-generated (though usually quite well). See [this old answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/36267/2253) for an example of the GT synthesiser getting confused by non-standard spelling.

Comment: @janus https://translate.google.ca/?sl=auto&tl=zh-TW&text=huy%E1%BB%81n&op=translate, I don't think it's the same if google is right.

Comment: No, you’re right – listening more closely, it sounds like _huyền_ is (3)23 or maybe just 33, and _tàng_ is 34 or something like that. Both do sound slightly rising, but _huyền_ is a bit lower throughout. _Tàng_ is definitely not falling. If you listen to them [in immediate succession](https://translate.google.com/?sl=vi&text=Bảo%20tàng.%20Tàng.%20Huyền.%20Tàng), it’s clearer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet OK, it seems that Google's voice is far from the tone contour defined in Wikipedia for standard Vietnamese. So, how could an average vn person think Google's voice sounds unwired?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be specific to Google. Compare the following recordings on Forvo, across several Vietnamese accents; all these examples have the *huyền* tone in the final position:

- [bảo tàng](https://forvo.com/word/b%E1%BA%A3o_t%C3%A0ng/#vi)
- [viện bảo tàng](https://forvo.com/word/vi%E1%BB%87n_b%E1%BA%A3o_t%C3%A0ng/#vi)
- [Hang Sơn Đoòng](https://forvo.com/word/hang_s%C6%A1n_%C4%91o%C3%B2ng/#vi)

To my ear, the Google recording as cited above has a *huyền* tone that [is long, quite breathy](https://translate.google.ca/?sl=auto&tl=zh-TW&text=B%E1%BA%A3o%20t%C3%A0ng&op=translate) and does not fall very much at all, resulting in a level pitch. Substitute other *huyền*-tone words, and you get a [similar pattern](https://translate.google.ca/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=B%E1%BA%A3o%20t%C3%A0ng%2C%20huy%E1%BB%81n&op=translate). Non-final *huyền* tones become shorter, and the fall is a little more pronounced. Thus, we can only say that this is a "sentence prosody"-level intonational effect of this one Google voice. Compare that to the [Google voice for the *ngang* tone](https://translate.google.ca/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=B%E1%BA%A3o%20t%C3%A0ng!%20B%E1%BA%A3o%20tang!&op=translate).

Note that I will say this *does* sound somewhat artificial. Does it impede comprehension? I personally don't think so; it's low enough that it's distinct from *ngang*, breathy enough to be distinguished from (Northern!) *nặng* (the description in the OP actually sounds more like Southern *nặng*), and doesn't rise nearly enough to sound like (Northern) *hỏi*.